# How to send a text file contents as mail body using python boto3?

Tags: python, boto3

I have the below data in a text file

--------------------------Thu Jun  7 12:00:01 UTC 2018 -----------------------------

```
"Ec2InstanceId":"i-0ec314eafd40e5ad5"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-0200e84d07ff2c5ed"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-00a46fde81549e56b"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-02013e0f353f9aa79"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-0f5c65a35ef4a7a39"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-0bddc318b2a5d886b"

"Ec2InstanceId":"i-0e661050aadb9966c"
```

I want to send this data via mail using python boto 3 module.
Now I am able to send the mail, but the problem I am facing is that the layout is getting changed in the mail body.
everything is coming in a single line.
Below is some portions of my code snippet:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def read_file():
    content = []
    with open('test_instance_details.txt') as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            content.append(i.strip('\n'))
    return '\n'.join(content)

BODY_HTML = read_file()

CHARSET = "UTF-8"

client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)


try:

    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
    Message={
        'Body': {
            'Html': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': BODY_HTML,
            },

        },
        'Subject': {
            'Charset': CHARSET,
            'Data': SUBJECT,
        },
    },
    Source=SENDER,
)
```

I am newbie to python. Can anyone please help me figure out a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Following is the change I made in my code:

```
def read_file():
    contents=open('test_instance_details.txt','r')
    return '<br/>'.join(contents.readlines())
```